# Adding Google_analytics for iOS is not working tried many ways?

Tags: ios, architecture, undefined, analytics, symbols

Hi I'm getting following error and so far not able to fix it.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GAI", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o objc-class-ref in HomeViewController.o  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GAITrackedViewController", referenced from: _OBJC_CLASS_$_HomeViewController in HomeViewController.o "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_GAITrackedViewController", referenced from: _OBJC_METACLASS_$_HomeViewController in HomeViewController.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance !

Comment: What version of Google Analytics SDK are you using?

Comment: Hi GenieWante i am using GoogleAnalyticsServicesiOS_3.09

Comment: u were imported the lib.sqlite3.0 file

Comment: Yes Anbu.Karthik i have imported lib.sqlite3.0 file

Comment: FWIW, save yourself a world of trouble and just change to parse.com for analytics.  Ridiculously simpler.

Comment: Yeah,Joe i have used parse but its the client requirement

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Had same problem till I added the `libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a` and `libsqlite3.0.dylib` to "Link Binary with Libraries"

Here is my full list:

[image]

Answer (score 11):

I have tried reproducing the issue that you've been facing and ended up with the same error you got. But, I was able to fix it. What I have done is, I have added the file `libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a` from the SDK folder to my project. Then, I added `libsqlite3.0.dylib` to the Link Binary With Libraries in the `Build Phases` tab. It worked!!!!

PS: Make sure you've added all the headers and mentioned frameworks in your project. The key is to include `libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a`and `libsqlite3.0.dylib`.

Comment: Hi Genie,I have done the same process but i cant manage the issue.

Comment: Okay nanbaa.. Do you use the libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a file added in the Link Binary With Libraries section?

Comment: Yeah.I have used libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a

Answer (score 2):

The suggestion here worked for me to add both libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a and libsqlite3.0.dylib. I am building a swift project and would upvote answer 1 if I had the privileges.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem is solved by the following steps:

```
pod init
```

Open Podfile paste the following lines(Change the Projectname to your project name)

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Projectname' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!


  # Pods for Projectname
  pod 'GoogleAnalytics'

  target 'ProjectnameTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'ProjectnameTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```